# How to stop an infinit loop in java desktop application to move the mouse

Tags: java, jframe, jbutton, mouse, infinite-loop

I'm trying to create a desktop program to move the mouse until I press for example the letter "q" in java.
I've created a window (JFrame), when I press a buttom the mouse start to move.
My doubt is related to this part:

```
while (true) {
        for (int j = 1500; j <1600; j++) {
            robot.mouseMove(j, 0);
            robot.delay(100);
        }
    }
```

How can I stop this infinit loop by pressing a letter?

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_Q) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

why this is not working?
(I need to press a letter because the mouse, while the program works, is unusable)
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you might have to let go of the event handler.
If this while(true) is ran on the awt event queue, you are hogging the whole GUI and no wonder it is not responsive; no other event can be fired until you return from the mouse event.

Can you give more code? This is not enough to explain the behavior.

You would probably need to launch a thread to perform this work.

UPDATE:

instead of calling synchronously your JavaRobot(); method, you will need to run it in a thread. Ugly hacked version for testing:

```
(new Thread(() -> JavaRobot())).start();
```

The cleaner version would likely save thread in a variable so you can interrupt it with another button. You can also go nuts with the executor services apis if you prefer not handling threads yourself yet still run tasks in threads.

Comment: Here you have the code, I thought I need threads, will investigate that.

Comment: exactly what I thought.

Comment: You can hack your code just to check with an ugly
new Thread(() -> JavaRobot()).start();
but don't click twice or it will start a second robot loop, etc...